# MySQL: Make a blog-style page with different data types at different points

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to develop something similar to this with PHP and MySQL: http://a-bittersweet-life.tumblr.com/

I'd like to make a page that is mostly made up of words, but can be interspersed with images or embedded videos or other data types. I'm not sure exactly how to do this, but I have an idea:

```
id | entry_date |  text | image_link | vid_embed | sound_embed
 0 |   June 1st |  data |    null    |   null    |  null 
 1 |   June 1st |  null |    data    |   null    |  null   
 2 |   June 1st |  null |    data    |   null    |  null  
 3 |   June 1st |  data |    null    |   null    |  null  
 4 |   June 2nd |  data |    null    |   null    |  null   
 5 |   June 2nd |  null |    null    |   data    |  null   
 6 |   June 2nd |  data |    null    |   null    |  null  
 7 |   June 2nd |  null |    data    |   null    |  null   
 8 |   June 2nd |  null |    data    |   null    |  null   
 ....
 ....
 ....
```

So, for each blog entry, the Date is displayed first, followed by the order in which data was put into the SQL table (ordered by id):

**June 1st**

- Text
- Image
- Image
- Text

**June 2nd**

- Text
- Video
- Text
- Image
- Image

Is there another way to do this, or does this seem like a fairly practical way to do it?

Comment: Do you use `php` or `js` together with `mysql`?

Comment: Yes, I use all three

Comment: The answers below appear to be giving generic implementations of how to fetch and display data from tables kinda close to OP's, which makes me question my understanding of the question.  OP:  Is your question "how do I display this data via PHP?" or is it "what's a good database structure to store this content?"

Comment: The question was "what's a good database structure to store this content?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple example which is use plain php. If you use some php framework you can replace some parts into more simple, but here is the GIST.

I'ver created 2 functions, so you can create classes and methods or build MVC or even use this functions, it is only concept...

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
// This function will provide data from DB.
// Here I`ve skipped validation
// because I had relied on PHP7 scalar type declarations.
function getDataFromDB(int $limit, int $offset) {
    $db = new \PDO('mysql:dbname={YOUR_DB};host={YOUR_HOST}', '{USER}', '{PASS}');
    // Here I`ve used super simple SQL,
    // but you can improve it
    // and filters by date or author or category or something else...
    $sql = sprintf(
        '
            SELECT *
            FROM {YOUR_TABLE_NAME}
            ORDER BY entry_date DESC
            LIMIT %d OFFSET %d
        ',
        $limit,
        $offset
    );
    // In this query, I`ve only provided params for pagination
    // because they are required on the first stage...
    $s = $db->prepare($sql);
    if (!$s->execute()) {
        throw new \RuntimeException($s->errorInfo());
    }
    // Next param is very IMPORTANT,
    // it will group data into array with format where:
    // key - date and value - array of posts, like:
    // array (
    //   'June 1st' => array (
    //     0 => array ('text' => '...', 'image_link' => ...),
    //     1 => array ('text' => '...', 'image_link' => ...),
    //   ),
    //   'June 2nd' => array (
    //     0 => array ('text' => '...', 'image_link' => ...),
    //     1 => array ('text' => '...', 'image_link' => ...),
    //     2 => array ('text' => '...', 'image_link' => ...),
    //     3 => array ('text' => '...', 'image_link' => ...),
    //   )
    // )
    return $s->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_GROUP | \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
```

Now you can use this function with purpose grab data from db and pass it to next function which will prepare html or json or something else...

```
// This function will render data.
function render(array $data) {
    $html = '';
    foreach ($data as $day => $posts) {
        // Caption for certain day, like 'June 1st' or 'June 2nd'.
        $html .= sprintf('<div class="dayPosts"><div class="day">%s</div>', $day);
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            // Particular blog post.
            // It is super simple HEREDOC example,
            // but you can do here anything you wish.
            $html .= <<<"BLOGPOST"
                <div class="post">
                    <h3>{$post['title']}</h3>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="{$post['image_link']}">
                        <p class="text"{$post['test']}></p>
                        <video controls>
                            <source src="{$post['vid_embed']}" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>
BLOGPOST;
        }
        $html .= '</div>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Here I`ve used plain php functions with purposer to prepare html, but you cna use something better like`twig`or`volt`or`smarty` or something else. Alsom you can put this function into view or refactor somehow...

And last step, connect all together:

```
// Now you can get and render your content.
echo render(getDataFromDB(20, 0));
```

PS: Ti is only the raw example... But now must have idea what to do next!

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the easy way to do this is to get all the rows and then iterate through them and use an if statement to determine the type.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Schema.Table WHERE CAST(entry_date AS DATE) BETWEEN '06/01/2017' AND '06/02/2017' ORDER BY id";
/* Query your database however you might do */

$lastDay = null;
while ($row in $sqlResult->fetch_row()) {
    if ($row->entry_date != $lastDay) {
        $lastDay = $row->entry_date;
        echo $row->entry_date;
    }
    if ($row->text != null) {
        echo $row->text;
    } else if ($row->vid_embed != null) {
        echo '<videoplayer src="' + $row->vid_embed + '">';
    } else if ($row->image_link != null) {
        echo '<img src="' + $row->image_link + '">';
    } else if ($row->sound_embed!= null) {
        echo '<soundplayer src="' + $row->sound_embed+ '">';
    }
}
```

This is a bit psuedo-code-ish, but the methodology should work without issue.

Comment: Why don't you use PDO?

Comment: You certainly can. It doesn't change the methodology. This is just pseudo code. How you access the data is up to you.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak is PDO preferred? Why?

Comment: @coffeebot At least because mysql extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: What about mysqli vs PDO?

Answer (score 1):

Or take a tip from HTML.

```
blah blah -- text
<img src=...> -- image
etc.
```

Or have two columns; one saying the MIME type (or however you wish to categorize them), one with the data in question.

Another tip from HTML:  Don't put the image or video or sound in the table cell; put a 'link' to it.